# Generate new ObjectId using RoboMongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have push an object in array of objects mongoose using robomongo

```
db.getCollection('model').update({_id:ObjectId('')},{$push : {array : {Object}}})
```

but this didnt created the ObjectId oin document. now i have to manually insert the ObjectId. Question is how to generate it and update the document

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have new Object ID by `ObjectId()`
For Example

```
x = ObjectId()
```

In this example, the value of x would be:

```
ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011")
```

for Further 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/